# Numerical methods for solving a hyperbolic nonlinear PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

What type of numercial methods are there to solve PDE of the sorts of: 
$$f(x,t,u(x,t))u_{xx} - g(x,t,u(x,t))u_{tt} = F(x,t,u(x,t))$$
$$u(x,0)=G_1(x) , \frac{\partial u(x,0)}{\partial t}=H_1(x) ,u(0,t)=G_2(t) , \frac{\partial u(0,t)}{\partial x} = H_2(t)$$ 
Where $f,g,F,u \in C^\infty(x,t) , \ G_i,H_i \in C^\infty$. 
Specifically I had in mind the PDE:
$$u_{xx}u^3-\sin(xt)u_{tt} = u$$

But the general PDE is as above; I looked at Polyanin's second edition Handbook of Nonlinear PDE table of conetents, and didn't find something similar, obviously I look at numerical solutions since an analytical solution doesn't seem plausible, but if there is I wouldn't mind. :-)

I posted this question also here:
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/numerical-methods-for-solving-a-hyperbolic-nonlinear-pde

hope it doesn't bother anyone.

Comment: Another site of relevance for this question is [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Crossposted there: http://scicomp.stackexchange.comquestions/20643/. (Please don't crosspost, at least not without pointing it out! Otherwise people waste their time writing an answer you have already received at another site.)

Comment: @ChristianClason I added a remark in both posts clearing out that I posted this question in two different stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 5):

I will let the SciComp people address the issue of the actual numerical method. Instead I will point out that your PDE, as written, is not necessarily hyperbolic. In particular, you see that $\sin(xt)$ can change signs, and $u^3$ can change signs. This means that depending on the parameters your PDE is actually of mixed type: at some regions it is hyperbolic, on some regions it is elliptic, and on some boundary portions it is degenerate/parabolic.

Unless you can a priori rule out these type changes (which I don't see how, since $\sin(xt)$ is independent of the solution $u$ or its initial data), if you try to solve this problem numerically as an initial value problem, your code will have "terrible, horrible, no good very bad" instabilities.

Also, when $t = 0$ your equation reduces to an ODE on the line. So your initial data $G_1$ is actually *not* free. Because all these considerations, it is not even clear to me that your problem is well-posed, never mind admitting a numerical solution method.

Comment: In fact, I'd be surprised if it were well-posed since the left boundary conditions are over-specified -- that's a lateral Cauchy problem, which for linear elliptic equations is literally the textbook example of an ill-posed problem. (Of course, with a nonlinear equation like this, who knows...)

Comment: Hi Willie Wong, can you prove that the problem as stated is ill-posed? What if I were to change $\sin(xt)$ with $\sin^2(u)$, and $u^3$ with $u^2$.BTW, I have another question from an ultrahyperbolic PDE which I hope you can address it appears here:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212978/a-question-on-theorem-1-1-of-fritz-john-ultrahyperbolic-pde

Comment: @Alan: if you make the replacement as you indicated, then away from the points where $\{u(x,t) = k\pi\}$ your equation is hyperbolic. That gives a bit more hope.

Comment: BTW, Willie why does it matter for well posedness that the problem is the same type in most parts of the domain? (the types are elliptic , hyperbolic and parabolic).

Comment: How do you suggest me to show ill posededness of the original problem, in case I pick as initial conditions trig functions such as sine and cosine?

Comment: @Alan: (a) the conditions for wellposedness are different for elliptic and hyperbolic problems. (For example, very classically [Hadamard?] we know that for second order elliptic PDEs the "Cauchy problem" is ill-posed; while that is basically the definition of hyperbolicity.) So having it true on "most of the domain" is not good enough, in general.  (b) At $t=0$ firstly a necessary condition is that $G_1(x)$ solves the equation $G_{xx} G = G$. Simple trig functions do not solve it; this already shows that it would be impossible to solve your equation with such initial data.

Comment: @WillieWong you meant that it should solve: $G_{xx}G^3=G$. I agree that simple trig won't satisfy such an ODE, do you know some special function that does satisfy this ODE?

Comment: @WillieWong in order to find a suitable boundary condition for this probelm I need to solve $y''=1/y^2$, which can be solved by multiplying by $y'$ and integrating once to get the following equation: $y'=\sqrt{-2/y+C}$, another integration leads to: $\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{-2/y+C}}=x+C_1$, which can be solved, we get an implicit solution for $y(x)$.